# Show CSS menu item selected by default using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I have created a menu bar using CSS and HTML. Menu bar contains sub-menu as well.

I am able show menu-item on hover of main menu item etc. But now I need Menu Item 2 (or one menu item), to be hovered/selected by default, (as soon as the page loads) and its related sub-menu items to be shown by default as well.
Please guide me through the same.

I have tried adding a class on the first item using Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("get the id of the menu item").click(function(){
       $(this).parent().find("id of the menu item").addClass('class to be added');   
  }); //but what should be written in the class so that menu item is active and its sub menu items are shown by default
```

});

HTML Code :

```
<ul id="menu-main" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-24"><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-25"><a href="#">Test2</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-267" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-267"><a href="#">Sub Menu1</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-27"><a href="#">Test3</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33"><a href="#">S1</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34"><a href="#">S2</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="#">S3</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-278"><a href="#">S4</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-281" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-281"><a href="#">S5</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-258"><a href="#">Test5</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-253" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-253"><a href="#">Test6</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS :

```
ul.sub-menu{position:relative;
z-index:40;}
ul#menu-main ul {
display: none;
}

ul#menu-main li:hover > ul {
display: block;background-color: red;
} ul#menu-main {



position: relative;
display:inline-table;
top: 42px;
position: relative;
float:right;
margin-bottom: 0px;
clear: both;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
background: transparent!important;
list-style: none;
height: 60px;
font-family: BebasNeueRegular, Helvetica, Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}
 ul#menu-main:after {
 content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
ul#menu-main li {
float: left;
line-height: 60px;
z-index: 40;
margin-left: 15px;
}

 ul#menu-main li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
background: #f29919;

}
ul#menu-main ul li{ border-bottom:1px solid #eee;}
ul#menu-main ul li a:hover {
color: #818181;
background: #eee;

}


ul#menu-main li a {
display: block;
font-family: BebasNeueRegular, Helvetica, Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
padding: 0 20px;
color: #818181;
text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu-main ul {
border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
ul#menu-main ul li {
float: none; 

position: relative;
list-style:none;
/*width: 180px;*/
line-height: 37px;
margin-left: 0px;
}ul#menu-main ul li:first-child{border-top: 1px solid white;}

ul#menu-main ul ul li a:hover {
color:white;
}

ul#menu-main ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:-1px;
}
ul#menu-main li.current-menu-item > a{
color: #fff;
}


ul#menu-main ul ul li:hover a{
color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need jQuery for this?

Your menu opens on hover, let's find the part which opens the menu:

```
ul#menu-main li:hover > ul {
  display: block;background-color: red;
}
```

Then add here another class to make it active:

```
ul#menu-main li:hover > ul,
ul#menu-main li.menu-item-active > ul {
  display: block;background-color: red;
}
```

Add the newly added menu-item-active class to the element we want to be active:

```
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-active menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-25"><a href="#">Test2</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-267" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-267"><a href="#">Sub Menu1</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And when you load the page, the element will be active.

But you might want to remove this class when user hovers other elements, so here we'll add a bit of jQuery:

```
$('ul#menu-main li:not(.menu-item-active)').hover(function() {
    $('.menu-item-active').removeClass('menu-item-active');
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LL3a55b3/

Comment: It's good, but menu item is white even though sub menus are visible, so let me play with css more. Anyway Thanks for the solution

Comment: Yes, I used only the CSS you provided above. If my solution works for you, please accept my answer so that it could help other people.

Comment: Sure that concept actually helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
This hover show sub-menu
```

[Use hover Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Sunildalal/j2xefscg/)

```
and This click show sub-menu
```

[Use click Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Sunildalal/j2xefscg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

On page load the browser will parse your HTML, build the page and add any css to the HTML elements. So you don't need JQuery, a class in the HTML and some css declarations will achieve what you want.

Add a class to the menu item you would like to be shown:

```
<ul class='sub-menu menu-shown-on-load'>
</ul>
```

The use this css:

```
.menu-shown-on-load {
    background-color: #ff0;
}
.menu-shown-on-load .menu-item {
    background-color: #ff0;
}
```

Where `background-color: #ff0;` could be any styles required to give the selected effect.